# Disable the background poi in Google Map javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map Javascript API v3, and there is a native feature which support the background poi(places of interest) inside the view port clickable like this:
[image]

I wonder if it is possible to disable this feature, I mean make the POIs un-clickable ?

Comment: Aha, maybe you misunderstand me , I want them be visible but un-clickable.

Comment: ah understood - but yes you're out of luck, as @geocodezip mentioned it's not possible with the maps api..it sucks i know

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks everyone.